# Retaining UITableViewCell selection statuses

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Why the `UITableViewCell`s don't reload the checkmarks after selecting, scrolling away, then scrolling back?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    #define CHECK_NULL_STRING(str) ([str isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || !str)?@"":str

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"inviteCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#669900"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [[UITableViewCell appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#669900"]];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    }

    if (cell == nil) {cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; }

    BOOL isSearching = tableView != self.tableView;
    NSArray *arrayToUse = (isSearching ? searchResults : contactsObjects);
    id p = arrayToUse[indexPath.row];

    NSString *fName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(p), kABPersonSortByFirstName));
    NSString *lName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(p), kABPersonSortByLastName));
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", CHECK_NULL_STRING(fName), CHECK_NULL_STRING(lName)];

    BOOL showCheckmark = [[stateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    if (showCheckmark == YES)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        NSLog(@"It hit showCheckmark = YES, and stateArray is %@",stateArray[indexPath.row]);
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        NSLog(@"It hit showCheckmark = NO, and stateArray is %@",stateArray[indexPath.row]);
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    id object = contactsObjects[indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [stateArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] atIndex:indexPath.row];
        [selectedObjects addObject:object];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [stateArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] atIndex:indexPath.row];
        [selectedObjects removeObject:object];
    }

    //slow-motion selection animation.
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `stateArray` is being set correctly?

Comment: I always try to work backwards from a known point of "disagreement".

Comment: Check my edit. @Hot Licks

Comment: Ahh. It appears that I need to be sending an object to the `NSMutableArray`, b/c BOOL is primitive.  So I need to send an `NSInteger` to the `stateArray`

Comment: I just tryed `[stateArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] atIndex:indexPath.row];`
in the `else-if` but it didn't work.

Comment: Could it be because YES is not an object? Try @YES

Comment: That didn't work. I understand that this problem is totally because the `BOOL` value `YES` is not an object, I just can't figure out how to convert it to an object and properly store it in `stateArray` at `indexPath.row`

Comment: I've even tried `stateArray[indexPath.row] = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];`

Comment: What do you see when you dump stateArray?  `insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` should work just fine.  Or `insertObject:@YES`, since `@YES` produces an NSNumber of YES.

Comment: When I dump stateArray, all results are:  `It hit showCheckmark = NO, and stateArray is (null)`

Comment: Can you upload the code somewhere? do you initialize stateArray?

Comment: That's actually what the problem was. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213432/cells-keep-losing-their-checkmark-selection/21213475?noredirect=1#comment31947911_21213475    The code was using `insertObject` when it needed to be using `replaceObject`.. also I can't really figure out why my stateArray `NSMutableArray` isn't usable in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: All that's left to do is properly instantiate `stateArray`. I've already made the property and synthesized it, and have even done a lazy instantiation, why isn't the variable localized to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: Whoever down voted this, please change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell selection problem was not solved, even when `insertObject` was replaced with `replaceWithObject`, however, one should not waste time setting `BOOL` objects with an `NSInteger` inside an `NSMutableArray`. Instead, for cell selection memory, one should use `NSDictionary` like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary * selectedRowCollection;

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    self.selectedRowCollection = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{    
    id object = contactsObjects[indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self.selectedRowCollection setObject:@"1" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]]; 
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.selectedRowCollection removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
    }

    //slow-motion selection animation.
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL showCheckmark =  [[self.selectedRowCollection valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]] boolValue];

    if (showCheckmark == YES)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed out the `!` (inverse operator) on the following line meaning that the state will always be the same.

```
[stateArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[[stateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue]]];
```

It should be

```
[stateArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:![[stateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue]]];
```

Edit --- I've refactored both methods because it can be done with a lot less code and it will completely simplify the methods for you.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"inviteCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    BOOL isSearching = tableView != self.tableView;
    NSArray *arrayToUse = (isSearching ? searchResults : contactsObjects);
    id p = arrayToUse[indexPath.row];

    NSString *fName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(p), kABPersonSortByFirstName));
    NSString *lName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(p), kABPersonSortByLastName));
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", CHECK_NULL_STRING(fName), CHECK_NULL_STRING(lName)];

    BOOL showCheckmark = [stateArray[indexPath.row] boolValue];
    if (showCheckmark == YES) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id object = contactsObjects[indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [selectedObjects addObject:object];
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [selectedObjects removeObject:object];
    }
    stateArray[indexPath.row] = @(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark);
}
```

Comment: do you mean on the **else** in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: @WhiteHatPrince That's correct. You could also store the cell you get from calling the method -cellForRowAtIndexPath in a variable so that you don't have to call the method twice.

Comment: Alright I just did that and the checkmarks are still disappearing upon scroll-and-scroll-back

Comment: @WhiteHatPrince I've refactored the method and it should work perfectly now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the simplification @max_

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding what the last line(of your simplification) is doing, the one containing `stateArray`

Comment: Thanks to you again for the simplification.

Comment: @WhiteHatPrince it replaces the NSNumber found in stateArray at the index `indexPath.row` and sets it to `YES` if the cell's `accessoryType` is a checkmark, and `NO` if it's not.

Comment: Oh.. very very nice. didn't know you could do that, I'm replacing the top method right now

Comment: The use of `==` returns a boolean value. Think of it in the same way that an if statement is evaluated.

Comment: Awesome, but hum, those checkmarks are still deleting upon scroll.

Comment: I actually gtg but i will brb

Comment: @WhiteHatPrince I assume your arrays are nil then.

Comment: No. The names are already properly displaying in the uitableview

Comment: I don't see the "following line" anywhere in the original post.

Comment: @HotLicks the original post was changed to use the code in my answer, that's why you can't see it.

Comment: I looked at the edit history and did not see those lines.  I guess I didn't look closely enough.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a more object oriented approach. This will ensure that your code is flexible and displays correctly all the time.

For each item you wish to display in your table, have a corresponding object. You mentioned that you are displaying contacts, so let's suppose your object is called "Contact":

```
//Contact.h

@interface Contact : NSObject

@property BOOL selected;
@property NSString *name;

@end

//Contact.m
#import Contact.h
@implementation Contact

+ (id) contactWithName:(NSString*)name {
    Contact *nContact = [Contact new];
    nContact.name = name;
    nContact.selected = NO;
    return nContact;
}
@end
```

Then, just make your view work something like this:

```
//ContactView.m

@interface ContactView()

@property NSMutableArray *contacts;

@end

@implementation ContactView
@synthesize contacts;

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //get your contact list here. When creating contacts, be sure to assign their selected and their name as you require.
    contacts = @[[Contact contactWithName:@"John"], [Contact contactWithName:@"Jane"]];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"inviteCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];

    Contact *cellContact = [contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellContact.name;
    cell.accessoryType = cellContact.selected == YES ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Contact *cellContact = [contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cellContact.selected = !cellContact.selected;
    [contacts replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:cellContact];
    [tableView reloadData]; //to refresh without animation
    //[tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [tableView numberOfSections])] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop]; //to refresh with animation
}

@end
```

And boom, easy to use tables that always look right, queue properly, and are object oriented for easy maintenance later.

Comment: I do like this, however this is changing a lot of what's already done. Definitely very easy to read and fix but I'm not sure this is about to solve the problem, and I understand my way perfectly fine.

Comment: And the assignment of each contact would have to be something besides manual, as you did in the `viewDidLoad:` with `contacts = @[[Contact contactWithName:@"John"], [Contact contactWithName:@"Jane"]];`. Perhaps a for-loop could do that trick though

Comment: Indeed, this was not meant to be snap-in code but rather to illustrate the concept you could use to make cleaner, easy to follow and fix code. As for solving the issue, it should- I do it this way specifically to prevent the issues you're having :)

Answer (score -2):

You are not doing this `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil) {cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
}`

Allocating is necessary if cell is nil. Or it cause problem while scrolling.

Comment: That's not true. If the cell was nil, the tableview would throw an exception.

Comment: +1 to the person above me- if it wasn't allocating cells it'd be crashing, not just having display issues.